# How to determine if user is accessing from LAN?

Tags: php, ip

I need my PHP script to determine if the user is accessing it from the LAN or not.

I have used $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] till now, to determine if the user's ip falls within a private ip range, but it fails with ipv6.

Current code used...

```
if( filter_var($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], FILTER_VALIDATE_IP, FILTER_FLAG_NO_PRIV_RANGE | FILTER_FLAG_NO_RES_RANGE) ){                           
    echo "NOT private or reserved ip";
}else{
    echo "private or reserved ip";
}
```

... but it seems to fail by reporting my ipv6 as not private or reserved.

Comment: What code were you using that worked for IPv4?  What have you done to try and correct the issue?  IP6 addresses have a very different set of formatting rules and can even be variable length as opposed to the 32 bit number that makes up an IP4 address.  How are you trying to parse them?

Comment: Aren't IPv6 always 64bit with a variable length notation?

Comment: @DeadElvis I've got a LAN on `10.1.7.`

Comment: @d_inevitable: *Aren't IPv6 always 64bit with a variable length notation?* IPv6 addresses are 128bit.

Comment: edited question to show current code.

Comment: @d_inevitable http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6#Address_format

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what "unicast" means, but according to *Abstract*, this is what you need:
[RFC4193#3.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4193#section-3.1)

You may compare `Global ID` and `Subnet ID` with same values for your server.